# Can we login to Microsoft CRM server by using Jenkins? for CI/CD process?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, jenkins-cli

For CI/CD workflow, Can I use Jenkins to Connect Microsoft CRM and do import new CRM solutions and adding security roles to users, Create plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can leverage PowerShell for this tasks. There are several modules for interaction with Dynamics:

- Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell
- Handy.Crm.Powershell.Cmdlets

Here you can find examples: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2015/10/26/great-power-tools-for-crm-administrator-microsoft-xrm-data-powershell-module-part-i/

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to CRM. Same way, Can we use CRM plugin registration tool also by using PowerShell command line?

Comment: No. Plugins registration tool is pure UI application.
If your intention to deploy plugin assemblies and steps, then you should add them into Dynamics solution on your development organization, export it as managed solution and the import on target QA\STAGE\PROD organizations.